# Editing passwords alongside other form fields in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form that i am using to edit the email and other details of the user table. The other details are columns i have added to the user table.

I want to be able to edit the password and i have several options.

1. In the edit view, leave the password and confirm password fields blank(no values from the db are displayed in the password field) and allow the user to enter a new password. Only the admin has the ability to edit the users so i have not enter old password feature.
2. Decrypt the bcrypt encrypted password to plain text and populate the raw text password in the password field and change the form field to text instead of password.
3. Populate the password field with the bcrypt string stored in the password field of the user password.

Would it be possible to decrypt the user password in laravel?.

Comment: What stops you from just updating the password?

`$user->password = bcrypt($newPassword); $user->save()` There is NEVER a good reason to decrypt a password or keep it stored in plaintext.

Comment: Its the presentation to the user when editing alongside other form fields. In an edit form, what goes inside a password field?. The password format of black dots(characters) or password in plaintext or the long bcrypt hash straight from teh user table?.

Comment: `bcrypt()` produces different hash at different times. You can only check the hashed password with plain text using `Hash::check()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What stops you from just updating the password?

```
$user->password = bcrypt($newPassword); 
$user->save()
```

There is NEVER a good reason to decrypt a password or keep it stored in plaintext. In fact, bcrypt disables you from decrypting it.

To answer your question directly: Option 1 is the ***only*** option.

**Edit: Second question**

> Its the presentation to the user when editing alongside other form
>   fields. In an edit form, what goes inside a password field?. The
>   password format of black dots(characters) or password in plaintext or
>   the long bcrypt hash straight from teh user table?.

You can put whatever you want in there? You can leave it blank, or you can show stars, dots, whatever. What matters is how you handle it in the backend request.

Leave it empty, that way you can simply check in the backend if anything was put into the field:

```
if($request->has('new_password') {
    // update password
}
```